# Browser refuses to honor Set-Cookie header from cross-origin response

Tags: go, cookies, axios, cors

I'm struggling to get my front end to set an http cookie that's sent via the backend (and send it to the backend on subsequent requests). Specifically wanting to set a refreshToken for authentication purposes.

I know my backend is properly sending the cookie as the header from the login response looks as follows.

`Set-Cookie: refreshToken=someLongRefreshToken; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 19 Jan 2023 20:12:52 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`

[image]

This is how I'm sending my requests from the front end (setting the auth token via an interceptor).

```
const axiosAuth = axios.create({
  validateStatus: (status: number) => {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300; // default (200 - 299);
  },
  headers: {
    Accept: `application/json`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    withCredentials: true,
  },
});
```

Then in some component

`let res = await axiosAuth.get('http://localhost:9922/someRoute');`

Couple of notes

1. I'm fairly certain my issue is on the front end. If I login and send another request through Postman it works just fine. It gets the http cookie and passes it back to the api on subsequent requests.
2. While I see the cookie set-cookie in the response header, I'm not seeing it in dev tools (application/cookies).
3. The cookie is not being set as secure locally (so I don't have to use https)
4. I've made sure my api accepts the necessary headers/cors stuff. Here's my api router just so you can see the headers I'm setting.

```
r.Use(cors.Handler(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:3002"},
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Authorization", "WithCredentials", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token", "SelectedGroup", "Allow-Credentials", "Cookie"},
    ExposedHeaders:   []string{"Set-Cookie"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))
```

Let me know if there's any other information I need to provide.

Comment: 1. Attempts to expose the `Set-Cookie` header lead nowhere, since it's a [forbidden response-header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name). 2. Similar remark about `Cookie`, which is a [forbidden request header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header). 3. For a cross-origin request to successfully set a cookie, the server's CORS configuration must allow credentials (`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`).

Comment: @jub0bs I've added `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"` to the allowed headers. I still don't recieve the cookie in the backend. Also removed the other two you mentioned were useless.

Comment: @jub0bs I should note even without setting it explicitly the header of the response has the following

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3002`

Comment: 1. Listing the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header as an allowed header is useless; you can safely drop it from that list. 2. That an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header is present in the response is not made obvious by your question. You should provide more information.

Comment: I'm noticing now that your client code is incorrect: `withCredentials` is not a request header, but a property of the request. See https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config. Fix that and see if things improve.

Comment: @jub0bs Ahhh thank you, it was the withCredentials was in the wrong place. That fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Good stuff. I was initially puzzled when I saw `withCredentials` in your list of allowed request headers but now I understand. Needless to say, you can safely drop it from that list.

Comment: @Regis Seems like your issue is resolved. Maybe you can accept the answer so this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `withCredentials` in the wrong place in your client code: it's not a request header, but a property of the request. Instead of

```js
const axiosAuth = axios.create({
  validateStatus: (status: number) => {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300;
  },
  headers: {
    Accept: `application/json`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    withCredentials: true, // incorrect
  },
});
```

you should have

```js
const axiosAuth = axios.create({
  validateStatus: (status: number) => {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300;
  },
  headers: {
    Accept: `application/json`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true, // correct
});
```