# Sending cookies in a cross origin request

Tags: cookies, cors, cross-domain

I have a script in https://frontend.libfoobar.com/client. In this script, I made a Http request to grab some data from https://demo.entrydns.org/api/music:

```
const clicked = () => {
  fetch("https://demo.entrydns.org/api/music", 
    { headers: { crossDoman:true, credentials: "include"}})
.then(R => {
  R.json()
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
    .catch(err => alert("json error", err));
})
.catch(err => alert(err));
}
```

The above request works successfully to completion, indicating that the CORS set up is somewhat proper. However, the cookies of demo.entrydns.org that are in my current browser session are not sent in the above `fetch` request despite having done all that I could find in documentation available.

The cookies that I need have the attributes `HttpOnly`, `Secure`, and `SameSite: None` set.

CORS preflight to https://demo.entrydns.org/api/music responds with the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,crossdomain,credentials,*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://frontend.libfoobar.com
```

What is missing from above for the demo.entrydns.org cookies to be sent in a cross domain request invoked from frontend.libfoorbar.com?

The two websites above are fully functioning and publicly accessible. I hope someone can go through the Http transactions and help me find out what I have done wrong.

Comment: In your client code, `credentials: "include"` is in the wrong place; it should be at the root of the object, not in `headers`: `fetch("https://demo.entrydns.org/api/music", {credentials: "include"})`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. I also had a typo in `crossdomain`.

Comment: @jub0bs Maybe post it as an answer so the question can be closed?

Comment: @Wilt I'd rather close it as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111853/browser-refuses-to-honor-set-cookie-header-from-cross-origin-response/75396175, but I cannot because my answer there has not been accepted or upvoted.

Comment: @jub0bs Upvoted now, maybe you can try again...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser refuses to honor Set-Cookie header from cross-origin response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111853/browser-refuses-to-honor-set-cookie-header-from-cross-origin-response)