# Cookie doesn't get sent event though set-cookie goes trough to the frontend

Tags: go, http, cookies, cors, nuxt.js

I have a golang gin backend hosted on `localhost:8080` and a NuxtJS frontend on `localhost:3000` with the following cors settings:

```golang
r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Content-Type"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
}))
```

The following request is being sent to the backend by the frontend and we expect a cookie back with the session:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Credentials": 'include',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(postData),
});
```

Then the backend sets the cookie like this:

```golang
c.SetSameSite(http.SameSiteNoneMode)
c.SetCookie("session", session, 3600, "/", "localhost", true, true)
```

And this is the backends response:

```
Set-Cookie: session=90fa4453-4ddd-48cf-910f-f7ac9e5a1cba; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Max-Age=3600; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
```

Even though i can see the Set-Cookie header in the response from the backend it doesn't seem to be set in the storage of the browser.

Comment: Different backend language, but same frontend issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75396175/2541573

Comment: Besides, browsers reject attempts by insecure Web origins like `http://localhost:3000` to set a cookie marked `Secure`.

Comment: As jub0bs mentioned: Secure needs https, it cannot work. Besides: Domain cookies on localhost _mostly_ work, but are pretty strange. Don't set domain and don't set secure on localhost.