# React application discarding cookies, when the same code in plain HTML/JavaScript does not

Tags: reactjs, cookies, cors, fetch-api

The React application does the following CORS fetch:

```js
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    credentials: "include",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ user: { email, password } }),
});
```

The response from the server includes the following:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3001
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age: 7200
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag: W/"36cb9f6def08029b9c6bff3c14a98017"
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server-Timing: sql.active_record;dur=23.10, start_processing.action_controller;dur=0.27, instantiation.active_record;dur=6.83, process_action.action_controller;dur=274.12
Set-Cookie: CSRF-TOKEN=UrU9vCDa-ni5ZWXUOIgaEEeGL4izouMAEFpa3oJWTH0dAUOIUH5yZDEogo9opprqe6r3YEoMxl0w4aT18zvIMQ; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: _session_id=4Aj5KMcZZG0Bn7EL4hhfdZHt0rw6WX46tpA9Lb8uE09apmDiALhiSAkGeUDIZuNvRJ9yTcUEbhydbFIgKYOkNPcMXrz7wItdWWjJSVsy%2Bfrp43uTxALrEsxVI%2BrvHrqfUTkM2FyP9MhqI8X1GPvbuIge%2FF4Acapi%2FuyPrmOqn9MMNqwqyJA%2Fo8GjtaU7vb4GzhDVxWOUQuVmKHm%2BCw2wGB4GsH%2Bv0QO1C%2BOYZE2PTVfeuONCWaXchyY21C0MVFnYYsZ2eB48c2
```

etc.  The second cookie has been truncated, but both have the same cookie parameters.

When I look in Chrome developer tools for the cookies, they are not present.

When I do exactly the same fetch code as above, to the same server, in the same browser, with the same CORS configuration, but I do this in ordinary JavaScript -- no React -- the cookies are set, and can be sent on subsequent fetch requests.

What is React doing that is causing the cookie not to be set?  What flows over the network, in both directions (including the prefetch) is exactly the same in both cases.  The only difference between the failing case and the working one is the use of React.

I expected that a successful CORS request from React could set a browser cookie.  The cookies are `SameSite=None`, `secure=true`, because that is what the Chrome folks recommend for cookies that are to be included with subsequent fetch requests.  Note that the request did succeed, and that the cookies were returned.  But, for the React case only, they were discarded.

Comment: If you're puzzled by the differences you observe, inspect (in the Network tab of the DevTools) the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header of the preflight request; all the header names listed there must be listed in the preflight response's `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` for things to work. In your case, the preflight response should at the very least contain `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests.

Comment: I've also just noticed a mistake in your client code: the `credentials` property is in the wrong place. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111853/browser-refuses-to-honor-set-cookie-header-from-cross-origin-response

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I am blind.  The code I used in the html/javascript app had credentials: "include" in the right place.  The above code, from the react app, has credentials: "include" in the wrong place, as someone observed. Gee.